# Is it possible to embed HTML in an iframe directly?

Tags: html, iframe

I have an HTML file (generated by the Notion app) and I'd like to embed it into my website as a blog post.

If the HTML is hosted, then I can embed it in an iframe by setting its `src` to the link address.  However, I don't have the HTML hosted, I just have a file with the raw HTML.  I've tried just pasting the HTML directly inside the iframe tags, but that doesn't work as I'd hoped.

My website is hosted by Squarespace and therefore I cannot upload the HTML file directly (or at least, as far as I know, this is not possible).  I can only "inject" raw HTML text into an embed block.

So is there a way to take an entire HTML file, and copy-paste it into some kind of an HTML element (like an iframe) so that the element will render as an element in the larger page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible with the [`srcdoc` Attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_srcdoc.asp).
Just be careful with quotes(`"'`) breaking the page. Here is a fully working example Bootstrap 5 page embedded directly into the `iframe` `srcdoc` attribute. Note the example is enclosed in single-quotes while only using double-quotes, so no escaping is necessary in this case.

```css
iframe {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 70vh;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <h1>The iframe srcdoc attribute</h1>

  <iframe srcdoc='
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-aFq/bzH65dt+w6FI2ooMVUpc+21e0SRygnTpmBvdBgSdnuTN7QbdgL+OapgHtvPp" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 class="text-bg-primary">Hello, world!</h1>
    <p>
  <a class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="collapse" href="#multiCollapseExample1" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="multiCollapseExample1">Toggle first element</a>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#multiCollapseExample2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="multiCollapseExample2">Toggle second element</button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".multi-collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="multiCollapseExample1 multiCollapseExample2">Toggle both elements</button>
</p>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="collapse multi-collapse" id="multiCollapseExample1">
      <div class="card card-body">
        Some placeholder content for the first collapse component of this multi-collapse example. This panel is hidden by default but revealed when the user activates the relevant trigger.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="collapse multi-collapse" id="multiCollapseExample2">
      <div class="card card-body">
        Some placeholder content for the second collapse component of this multi-collapse example. This panel is hidden by default but revealed when the user activates the relevant trigger.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
    
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-qKXV1j0HvMUeCBQ+QVp7JcfGl760yU08IQ+GpUo5hlbpg51QRiuqHAJz8+BrxE/N" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
' src="">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>

</body>

</html>
```